# Socket Program to demonstrate Link layer communication in a network without using ip address

Tags: c, sockets, networking

As we all know that within a network, communication is by the MAC address and not by the ip address. So I always used to think that whether we can write a socket program in server-client paradigm which are only using MAC address for communication but not ip address i.e. the struct sock_in should be left unfilled, and within a lan they should be able to communicate.

Comment: You can certainly write such a program, yes.  Do you have a question?

Comment: can you give me some idea how to write such a program since i have wrote many programs using socket programming in C but never tried this one..can you please give me some hint.

Comment: but it is filling the ip address structure in the code;  host_address.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
it is not based on hardware address

Comment: Did you read far enough along?  The first example there is UDP, the second is raw ethernet.

Comment: ohh sorry thanks a lot for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw sockets, as given by the example above (by Carl) can work to give you access for L3 header. However, note that on more up-to-date Windows (XP SP3, Vista and 7) raw sockets are greatly restricted by the socket layer, making it difficult to send arbitrary data of your choosing.

You can also use special libraries that allow for a much more raw access to the Ethernet adapter. [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) (for Windows) or [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) (for Linux) will allow you to manipulate the entire packet data, including the Ethernet header, and indeed send any other L2 protocol you wish.

Comment: Does that restriction apply when I want to send ARP packet with `socket()` and `sendto()` in Windows?

Comment: Yes. Since ARP is an between L1 and L2 (kind of L1.5), you don't get direct control over ARP packets and you can't generate them from the standard `socket`

Comment: I have a question about this issue. Can you provide an answer in that question? See my profile and you find the question.